# Java regexp, get characters within delimited string ignoring text in between

Tags: java, regex

I have a string such as;

```
One Two Three|null:Two Two Three|10:Two Three|10:Six Two Three|null
```

My regex pattern is:

```
(^|:)+Two Three(?!\|null)
```

This pattern returns

```
Two Three|10
```

but it does not return

```
Two Two Three|10
```

as well. How would I go about skipping the text between ":" and "Two Three"

UPDATED:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|[: ])+("+searchString+")(?!\\|null)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 Matcher m = p.matcher("One Two Three|null:Two Two Three|10:Two Three|10:Six Two Three|null");

 System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with space also as preceding character:

```
(?:^|[: ])((?:Two )+Three)(?!\|null)
```

In Java:

```
String re = "(?:^|[: ])((?:Two )+Three)(?!\\|null)";
```

Same thing with lookbehind:

```
(?<=[: ]|^)(?:Two )+Three(?!\|null)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS0gP1/2)

**Code:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|[: ])("+searchString+")(?!\\|null)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 Matcher m = p.matcher("One Two Three|null:Two Two Three|10:Two Three|10:Six Two Three|null");

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Works perfect in regex DEMO, thank you! I modified it slightly as the search string can vary. (?:^|[: ])+(searchString)(?!\\null) but when I implement it in Matcher it does not match anything.

Comment: You omitted `\|` before `null`.

Comment: Yes in the above statement I did, but not in my code, I edited my post up top to reflect it.

Comment: I used matches, it worked, however I have ran into another snag, I realize I may have options such as One Two Three Four|10:One Two Three Four|null, etc... so I changed the patter to look like this; (?<=[: ]|^)(Two Three)(?![ ]|^)(?!\null) it works in RegEx DEMO, but not im my Pattern compile

Comment: Did you try: `Pattern.compile("(?<=[: ]|^)(Two Three)(?!\\null)");` Also I suggest you provide updated code so that I can take a look.